# Is there a branch of CS about studying function calls branching?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I know little about computer science. I wrote a function that has some ifs and may call itself recursively.

Is there a branch of computer science that studies these possible branches?

I'd like to analyze the possible branches and maybe generate a graph of all of them to study all possible outcomes of my function.

```
my_func(&mut self, request: Request, retry_count: i32) -> Result<(), FuncError> {
   let response = self.send(request);
   let response = match response {
       Ok(_) => return Ok(()),
       Err(Error::Unauthorized(unauthorized)) => Err(FuncError::Unauthorized(unauthorized)),
       Err(Error::ConnectionClosed) => Err(FuncError::ConnectionClosed{}),
       Err(_) => Err(FuncError::UnknownError{})
   }
   match response {
      Ok(()) => Ok(()),
      Err(Error::Unauthorized(unauthorized)) => {
           self.authorize();
           return self.my_func(request, retry_count -1),
      }
      Err(Error::ConnectionClosed) => {
           self.connect();
           return self.my_func(request, retry_count -1),
      }
      Err(_) => Err(FuncError::UnknownError)
   }
}
```

I'd like to generate a graph of all possible outcome for this Rust method, considering a small `retry_count` of `3` for example. Or maybe read more about some theory on how to analyze this function and know more about it, etc.

I don't think there's something ready for Rust, but maybe for C++. Maybe one that I can do manually, without parsing some language.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you been by `I'd like to generate a graph of all possible outcome for this Rust method, considering a small retry_count of 3 for example`, but it seems you are talking about [control-flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph) and/or [data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis), which are studied in [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis).

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity, perhaps?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you want to know.  I don't know what you mean by a "graph of all possible outcome" or a "graph of all of [the possible graphs]".  I suggest reading about control-flow graphs and see if they meet your needs, then coming back and [edit]ing your question to state your requirements more clearly.  Coding-specific questions (such as questions specific to Rust) are off-topic here.